# How do I create a dynamic set of pull down menus using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic

I am working on optimizing a form for our website that lets a user complete the it using pull down menus. I have figured out how to populate a single pull down menu based on a PHP query, but I then need another pull down menu to be populated based on that selection. I am attempting to use the onchange attribute for the select tag. I know that my query in the javascript is not dynamic yet, but I am just trying to get it to show the next pull down first, which it isn't. When I select something from the first pull down nothing happens. Thank you advance for any help.

```
$query2 = "select distinct Provider_Name from CE_ACTIVITY_LIST_T where IS_ACTIVE = 'YES'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $link) or die(mysql_error());
//$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='0'><tr><th>";
echo "Course Provider:</th><td><select name='providerName' id='provider'onchange='getResult()'>";
echo "<option SELECTED>Pick Provider</option>";
$i=0;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row2['Provider_Name'] . "\">" . $row2['Provider_Name'] . "</option>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</select></td></tr><tr></tr>";

<script type="text/javascript">
function getResult(field)
{
    var field=field;
    var isEqualTo=document.getElementById('provider');
    document.getElementById('selectCourse').innerHTML = '<?php
    include ('connectionOpen.php');
    $queryCourse="select Course_Title from CE_ACTIVITY_LIST_T where Provider_Name = 'Test 1' and isActive = 'YES'";
    echo "<tr><th>";
    echo "Course Title:</th><td><select name='courseTitle'>";
    echo "<option SELECTED>Which course?</option>";
    $i=0;
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $row2['Course_Title'] . "\">" . $row2['Course_Title'] . "</option>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td></tr></table>";
    ?>';

}
</script>
```

Comment: Just to verify, if you manually run these queries do you get the correct values?

Comment: Yes I know these queries work. I just don't understand how to run them onselect of pull down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to populate another list then you need to load it with ajax, you can use jQuery to make it easier. First create php script that will generate html for second option list, eg. myscript.php, this script should receive parameter name.

Be sure that jQuery is included. Then modify your javascript as follows:

```
function onChange()
{
    var name = providerName.value; 
    var url = "path-to-script";
    $.get(url, {name:name}  function(html){
        $("#result").html(html) 
    });
}
```

Instead of second option use  `<div id='result'></div>` as placeholder for new option list.

Comment: I apologize if this is an ignorant question, but I can't seem to figure out how to run the query in that script. What I have watched and read as demonstrated how to populate the pull down with values hardcoded into the html. But how do I run a PHP script to query, since that is the only way I know how to access the database.